# Drupal 6 and Opengraph 2.1

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-6, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I have a mission to a project in my work. I need to setup Metadata on a website (**Drupal 6**) with [Opengraph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph). After a lot of Google searches, I'm still lost.

There is a Drupal module called [Drupal for Facebook](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb).

Do I only have to set metadata like Facebook docs inside any page.tpl.php" and derivatives like:

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://your-site.com/your-image.jpg" />` ?

Or do I need to install the Drupal module because it's not compatible with Drupal 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Drupal for Facebook](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb), and because this question is about Drupal version 6, it appears to me that you must use [Release 6.x-3.3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1650844) of this module. For more details about how to get that to work, I would look in the [fb 3.x community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/912614).

I'd be interested to hear if that answers this question.